# SurveyMonkey API: Using existing email collector and/or HTML in body_text programmatically

Tags: email, surveymonkey

I am guessing there is no support for this, but need to confirm for a client.
I am using `send_flow` from the API. Is it possible to:

1. In any way add recipients to an existing  Email Collector? The reason is that automating surveys creates quite a few collectors if done daily or more frequently.
2. Is it possible to send in HTML in `email_message.body_text` programmatically? It does state *plain text* in the documentation, and it does not get converted and shows up in the email as plain text. If I use the same HTML-code in an Email Collector created in the SurveyMonkey-website, it works fine, but then again I have no way of using an existing collector it seems, as in question 1.
3. Continuing from question 2, if we can't send in HTML programmatically, is there a way to change the default email template? The API states "*Default template is used if this [`body_text`] is not specified*", but I can't see any option of customizing this in our client-accounts.

Have also considered using a Web Link Collector and send emails outside of SurveyMonkey. The challenge with that seems to be:

1. Can't register [CustomData] with the responses, which is vital for the analysis, without adding potentially large dropdowns inside the survey itself.
2. The Survey URL is not unique in terms of forwarding it, although this can be an acceptable risk.

Thanks a lot, any ideas or feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tony at SurveyMonkey this was solved by him pointing to Custom Variables in the Platinum version, then adding these to a Web Link Collector and sending the HTML email from our integrating application.
http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them

Answer (score 0):

The problem with web link collector is that there is no way to track response rate since SurveyMonkey doesn't know how many links were sent out. I don't know a way around this.